# Why Eigen (version 3.2.5) cannot get correct transposed matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I am using Eigen library to do basic matrix manipulation. However, I could not even get a right transposed matrix from a 3*3 matrix. The following is a simple code sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

Matrix3d m;

m << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9;
cout << "before transpose: " << endl;
cout << m;
cout << endl;

m = m.transpose();

cout << "after transpose: " << endl;
cout << m;


return 0;
}
```

The print result is:

```
before transpose:
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
after transpose:
1 2 3
2 5 6
3 6 9
```

The result is pretty wierd. I was wondering what's wrong with my code? I think Eigen couldn't have had such a obvious bug.

Comment: This is not a bug, you're using transpose wrong. See here: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a3c187c30922fc5e42f208ae3eb0970ee

Comment: If you compiled without `-DNDEBUG` (or in so called debug mode) you should have got an assertion telling you the origin of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

That's caused by an aliasing effect, similar to what would happen if you did:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
    a[i] = a[a.size()-1-i];
```

You have several ways to circumvent this. The less preferable method would be to use a temporary:

```
m = m.transpose().eval();
```

or, better, to tell Eigen that it's the same matrix and use

```
m.transposeInPlace();
```